# How to access extra data sent along with urbanairship push request using phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova, push-notification, urbanairship.com

How to access extra data sent along with urbanairship push request using phonegap/cordova?

Answer (score 0):

This is applicable only to android.

Data for the push notification being sent by the server.

```
{
   "audience": "all",
   "notification": {
      "alert": "Extras example",
      "android": {
        "extra": {
            "url": "http://example.com",
            "story_id": "1234",
            "moar": "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
         }
      }
   },
   "device_types": ["android"]
}
```

To access the extra data that is sent. You need to access the **`event.extras`**  parameter. Yes the data is sent as **`event.extra`** but you need to use **`event.extras`** to access it.

For example:

```
//if you have a handleIncomingPush callback registered with 
//the urbanairship.push event listener

var pushUrl;//global variable to store the url

document.addEventListener("urbanairship.push", handleIncomingPush, false);

 var handleIncomingPush = function(event) {

      if(event.extras.url)
      { 
       pushUrl  = event.extras.url);//you can use this url elsewhere 
       alert(pushUrl);//this will output http://example.com
      }
      if(event.message) {
        console.log("Incoming push: " + event.message);

      } else {
        console.log("No incoming message");
      }
    };
```